# how to check if vaules of a matrix and an array are equal in python

Tags: python-3.x

Given a matrix `mat` and an array `arr`, for each row of the matrix if elements of Column 1 are equal to the corresponding element of the array, then print the corresponding value of Column 2 of the matrix.

```
mat = np.array([['abc','A'],['def','B'],['ghi','C'],['jkl','D']])
arr = np.array(['abc','dfe','ghi','kjl'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved via [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Extract the first row of the matrix using `mat[:,0]`, and compare it to `arr` using `np.where(mat[:,0] == arr)` to extract the indexes.
and use those indexes to get the elements you want from `mat`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...:  
   ...: mat = np.array([['abc','A'],['def','B'],['ghi','C'],['jkl','D']]) 
   ...:  
   ...: arr = np.array(['abc','dfe','ghi','kjl'])                                                                                                                                                       

In [2]: print(mat[np.where(mat[:,0] == arr)])                                                                                                                                                           
[['abc' 'A']
 ['ghi' 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Output should be `['A', 'C']``

So above code can be modified as

```
print(mat[np.where(mat[:,0]=arr)][:,1]
# output ['A' 'C']
```